# How to mock an ethers provider while testing with jest?

Tags: testing, react, ethers.js, typescript

In the real app, I'm using the web3-react hook to inject the provider, etc. How do I best mock that/replicate that in a Jest Typescript environment?

Answer (score 4):

I was running with this problem and you can inject it with ganache-cli

`const ethereumObject = require("ganache-cli").provider();`

You can check out more here: https://michalzalecki.com/integration-tests-with-web3-ganache-cli-and-jest/ - I'm using ethers and it works!

Kinda late but I hope this helps someone

Comment: Also if you are into jest, here are some more example code https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80364/alternatives-for-truffle-for-running-and-writing-tests